# Is it possible to add a javascript for/while loop for location.reload();

Tags: javascript, loops, reload

My Wordpress site has conflicting plugins. So when I click a page in the menu, it get stuck but fixes when the page has been re-loaded.

My approach is to auto refresh the page (the menu link that has been clicked) so the page will properly load.

After searching for couple of days, I haven't found the exact way to do it.
I use

```
location.reload(true);
```

but it keeps reloading. I tried also

```
location.reload(true);
window.stop();
```

but it stops loading before it completes the page load to 100%.

So my question is, can we add a loop to stop the reload? 
example…

> after 2 reloads, the js code will stop

Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: keep count into localstorage

Comment: reloading the page is not really a solution to a bug

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of JavaScript, it stores the reload count in LocalStorage:

```
if(typeof(localStorage.getItem('rlcount')) == 'undefined'){
    localStorage.setItem('rlcount', 0);
}
if(localStorage.getItem('rlcount') < 2){
    localStorage.setItem('rlcount', localStorage.getItem('rlcount') + 1);
    window.location.reload();
}else{
    localStorage.removeItem('rlcount');
}
```

However, you should note that reloading a page is not a good fix for your bug, you should find the root cause.

Comment: This code works… actually, both comments works but in different approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I would encourage you to try to fix the root problem causing the behavior you described, you could do something like the following to reload the page twice:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loadedOnce';
        alert("Reloading first time...");
        window.location.reload();
    } else if (window.location.hash === "#loadedOnce") {
        window.location = window.location.hash.replace("#loadedOnce", "#loadedTwice");
        alert("Reloading second time...");
        window.location.reload();
    } else if (window.location.hash === "#loadedTwice") {
        // Page reloaded twice, do whatever...
    }   
}
```

This makes use of a hash in the URL, so it does not require using the `localStorage` API (although that is a perfectly fine approach too if the browser supports it, and might work better if you already have hashes in the URL).

Comment: Thanks! And yes you are indeed correct, I have to find the root cause of the problem which fortunately, I have. It was a plugin from the theme.

Comment: Awesome! :-) Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking time to answer my question guys…
I found a simple way (not a loop though). Not sure if this is ok but it's working when I added "return".

```
location.reload();
return;
```

When adding this command. it simply reloaded once.